# EXCEEDED_ID_LIMIT updating Contact records

Tags: c#, api, salesforce, integration

We are using the Partner WSDL in our C# integration with Salesforce and we are receiving the following error when trying to update more than 200 records:

Error updating Contact: EXCEEDED_ID_LIMIT: record limit reached. cannot submit more than 200 records into this call

How do we go about increasing this number? Is it possible or are we stuck with 200 records?

Thanks ahead of time for your resonse.

Comment: Is this response coming from the Web Service itself or from your code? If it's coming from the Web Service you will have to contact the creator. That or split the request up into multiple calls. This is probably a safeguard server side to keep the system running smoothly.

Comment: Looks like it may be possible using a Bulk Connection from the Partner: salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/Content/… We're going to try this, I'll post back our findings

Answer (score 2):

You can only update 200 records in a single request, you need to chunk your update up into sets of 200 and make multiple calls.

Comment: Looks like it may be possible using a Bulk Connection from the Partner: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/Content/asynch_api_code_walkthrough.htm  We're going to try this, I'll post back our findings.

Answer (score 0):

The web service administrators have probably limited each call to 200 records as a safeguard. This means less load on their servers and quicker response to the client.

You probably cannot change this limit unless you contact the web service administrator directly.

For now you should keep the limit in mind and make multiple requests of 200 records each instead of a single request.

**Note: Web services that limit the number of records returned per request will sometimes return an ID number. This usually allows the client to continue picking up records where they left off. Keep an eye out for this.**